# Пустые div'ы

Tags: css3, html5, css

Есть [таблица из пустых блоков](http://jsfiddle.net/YQu9w/). Если я задаю свойство **contenteditable='true'** в самом HTML (как в примере по ссылке), то все работает. Можно ли перенести это свойство в CSS-файл? Настораживает, что NetBeans ругается на неизвестное свойство.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

contenteditable - это атрибут элемента. Его можно указать при генерации страницы прямо в HTML или позже выставить из Javascript. Никакого отношения к CSS не имеет. Им же(CSS) и не управляется.

Если есть желание вынести атрибут "contenteditable" за пределы HTML - добавляйте его нужным элементам через Javascript в момент, когда это действительно нужно :)